# How can I terminate a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteUser] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@original_UserID nvarchar(64) = UserID,
@temp int =0

    AS
    BEGIN
SELECT @temp = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users WHERE ManagerID = @original_UserID
END

BEGIN
IF(@temp>0)

    RAISERROR ('This user is manager of other user',
           16, -- Severity.
           1 -- State.
           );
           //Error occurred / Terminate the stored procedure 
END

BEGIN
SELECT @temp = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Project WHERE ProjectManagerID = @original_UserID
END
```

I tried using return but it didn't work

P/S: I use this stored procedure in a girdview, which is contained in an updatePanel, I dont know this can cause problem or not

Comment: What are all those `BEGIN/END` blocks for? Can you show the whole `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?

Comment: At least show how you tried using `RETURN` that "didn't work".  It should work, and it can be placed in a conditional block.  Otherwise the stored procedure returns when the end of the procedure is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAISERROR will throw an exception to the nearest catch block. So adding exception handling to your code will give the desired effect..

```
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN
    SELECT @temp = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users WHERE ManagerID = @original_UserID
  END

  BEGIN
   IF(@temp>0)
     RAISERROR ('This user is manager of other user',
                16, -- Severity.
                1 -- State.
                );
                //Error occurred / jump to the catch block
  END

  BEGIN
    SELECT @temp = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Project WHERE ProjectManagerID = @original_UserID
  END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ...
END CATCH
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Just use the return statement:

```
RAISERROR('Error message', 16, 1)
RETURN
```

Comment: This needs to include both within a conditional block.

Comment: -1 For `I tried using return but it didn't work` to which you responded `Just use return`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use error trapping:

```
BEGIN TRY
<your current code>
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK

    SELECT  @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

    SET @Msg = 'Error in Procedure XYZ!' 
    RAISERROR(@Msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)  WITH NOWAIT
END CATCH
```

You can alter the `SEVERITY` of the error in the last `RAISERROR` to force a terminating error as well.